# Bold Greek letters in matlab latex interpreter

Tags: matlab, latex, matlab-figure

I tried using bold font for the Greek letters in my axis labels in Matlab but they don't seem to work.

For example:

```
xlabel('\mathbf{\rho}','Interpreter','latex')
```

I've tried other commands such as `\bf` but still it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use equation notation (as you would need in LaTeX) `$$` and `\boldmath`

```
xlabel('\boldmath$\rho$','Interpreter','latex')
```

`\boldmath` will make bold everything in the next equation after it, so if you want only only partly bold, then separate the equation

```
xlabel('\boldmath$\rho$ $_i$','Interpreter','latex')
```

If you want multiple things bold, the same. Separate the equation and add a `\boldmath` before each bold section.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work. But now what if I want to have $\rho_i$ in the label but without making the subscript bold?

In addition, what if I have an argument $\rho_i(\mu)$ in which I want both $\rho$ and $\mu$ to be bold? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use mbox to have everything in one single equation. [Source](https://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/boldmath.html)

```
xlabel('$\sqrt{\mbox{\boldmath $\rho$}_i}$', 'Interpreter','latex')
```